# Не получается задача: Вводиться список людей, и нужно вывести количество не повторяющихся фамилий

Tags: python, python-3.x

n - кол-во людей.
Затем идут фамилии(например, Иванов, Петров). Необходимо вывести количество не повторяющихся фамилий, сами эти фамилии выводить не нужно.

```
n = int(input())
a = []
b = []
count = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    a.append(str(input()))
for i in (0, n-1):
    for j in (i, n):
        if a[i] == a[j+1]:
            b.append(i)
res = len(a)-len(b)*2
if res>0:
    print(res)
else:
    print("NO")
```

Выводит ошибку: list index out of range по 9 линии

Comment: `for i in range(0, n - 1):` и `for j in range(i, n - 1):` тогда правильно

Comment: Выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0ik29Ux2 убедитесь что ваш код совпадает с этим

Comment: 9 "линия" это какая?

Comment: ``a.append(str(input()))`` - результат input() не нужно конвертировать в строку, оно уже сразу строка.

Comment: не совсем понял, нужно убрать дубликаты и посчитать или нужно посчитать те фамилии, которые встречались только один раз в списке `a`

Comment: Ой, спасибо. Совсем дурацкая ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Словари

Можно использовать `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

n = int(input())
surnames = [input() for i in range(n)]
surname_c = Counter(surnames)
cnt = sum((x == 1) for x in surname_c.values())
print(cnt)

## print(sum((x == 1) for x in Counter([input() for i in range(int(input()))]).values()))
```

Если нельзя библиотеки:

```
n = int(input())
surnames = [input() for i in range(n)]
surname_c = {surname: surnames.count(surname) for surname in set(surnames)}
cnt = sum((x == 1) for x in surname_c.values())
print(cnt)
```

Сокращенный вариант:

```
n = int(input())
surnames = [input() for i in range(n)]
cnt = sum((x == 1) for x in {surname: surnames.count(surname) for surname in set(surnames)}.values())
print(cnt)
```

### Без словарей

`filter`:

```
n = int(input())
surnames = [input() for i in range(n)]
cnt = len(list(filter(lambda x: x==1, (surnames.count(surname) for surname in set(surnames)))))
print(cnt)
```

`list comprehension`:

```
n = int(input())
surnames = [input() for i in range(n)]
cnt = len([(x==1) for x in (surnames.count(surname) for surname in set(surnames))])
print(cnt)
```

P.S. `sum` и `len` в данном случае взаимозаменяемы в обоих выборах (словари или без словарей).

Comment: `len([surnames.count(surname)==1 for surname in set(surnames)])`

Comment: `sum(1 for surname in set(surnames) if surnames.count(surname) == 1)`